# Set header using in React (ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

try set header, in Ajax Request using axios

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'

class Income extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

     this.state = {     
        };


  }


componentDidMount() {


 axios.post('http://139.196.141.166:8084/course/income/outline', {
      headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
    })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
    }





render() {

        return (
            <div>
                dsdss
            </div>
        )
    }
```

But server returns me, that I not setup header. I setup it like in documentation, but header is not set.

There screen with error

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see, the method call looks like this ([from docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#instance-methods)):

```
axios#post(url[, data[, config]])
```

As you are posting your `config` object as second argument, its interpreted as `data`, not as `config` (`headers` is part of the `config` object)

---

Edit: Here is an example:

```
axios.request({
  url: 'http://139.196.141.166:8084/course/income/outline',
  method: 'post',
  headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
})
```

Note that i switched over from .post() to .request() which only takes a config object. If you still want to use the .post() call, try:

```
axios.post(url, {}, { headers: ... })
```

Comment: Can you change it with my code? don't understand how to change

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко sure... added 2 examples

Comment: How do post call, with first example? I mean last part where I can make console.log

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко you would just use the returned Promise the same way (with .then() and .catch())