# I can't figure out how to make the api call for predictHQ api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I am trying to make an API call to show events in the area. 
I am kind of new to API calls especially on react. I have trying to call this API for the past few hours I've tried various things, but I think I just don't understand the API docs fully. I was wondering if anyone could take a look?  I can make a call from postman, but I'm not sure how to do it in react.
The response I am getting back from the console is a 401 (Client authentication failed)

I am just trying to call the API to the console for now.

Heres the docs: https://developer.predicthq.com/oauth2/

I would really appreciate any help, even its a better API than the one i'm using.
thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            events: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchApi();

    }

    fetchApi() {

        axios.get('https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/?q=music&city=galway&country=IE')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(parsedJSON => (parsedJSON.results))
            .catch(error => console.log('parse failed', error
            ))
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, events } = this.state;

        return (

            <div className={`content ${isLoading}? 'is-loading: ''`}>
                <div>
                    {
                        !isLoading && events.length > 0 ? events.map(event => {
                            return <div>
                                <p>Api: </p>
                            </div>
                        }) : null
                    }
                </div>

                <div className="loader">


                </div>

            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: why are the headers embedded in the Url ?

Comment: I was just trying various things, that was my last hope haha

Comment: where should the headers be?

Comment: Everything starting with Authorization should be in the headers, see here for how to set headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790854/set-header-using-in-react-ajax

Comment: Also it is a terrible idea to put your client secrets and tokens in public websites just FYI

Comment: I was thinking that, it's just for college anyway. Should the Auth and content-type also be put in the same as the headers?

Comment: Seriously though man, thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't matter why and how you are using it, you are putting the API provider's system at risk. Read about HTTP headers, what they mean and how they are used, the answer should be straight forward

Comment: Noted, and deleted the tokens, and secrets. Have a good one sir!!!